# Can an entire mailbox of deleted items be recovered in Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

Recently an employee deleted their entire mailbox before leaving the company and there was no litigation hold in place.

Is there any way to recover all of the deleted items, preferably via a PowerShell script? We'd need to recover all of the folders, subfolders, and online archives.

I realize we can recover emails one by one up to a point but this will take far too long to be feasible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long ago did this happen?

Comment: Yesterday, within the retention period.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a Multi-Mailbox search using PowerShell's [Search-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) with the `SearchQuery` parameter left empty.  After you've got the search results you want, you can export them to a .pst or copy them to a mailbox.  It will search the dumpster (where items go after being deleted from the Deleted Items folder) automatically.